# Delete document from document service (SCP)

Tags: cmis, sap-cloud-platform

I've used [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b0cc1109d03c4dc299c215871eed8c42/Cloud/en-US/ee63e43b719e4e5e94ad3fdbe84cc73f.html) tutorial to create a document service API and the documents are uploading just fine. I'm trying to delete a document now, but there doesn't seem to be much information on that subject.

Can I delete a document with a Delete request and the document ID or what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should delete request by passing the document id.

If you are using java CMIS client library, then [Session#delete](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/javadoc/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Session.html#delete-org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.ObjectId-) methods should be used.

Best Regards,

Saurav